# Trying to republish a google sheets add-on in the G Suite Marketplace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

My Google Sheets Add-on was in the Chrome Web Store and worked fine, I've been trying to move it to the G Suite Marketplace and had it published but it didn't work in any domain, so I unpublished it (not a good idea) and then re published it. It is now "under review" once again even though I made no changes. I did this well over a week ago. I'm not a developer or programmer, my son made this extension for me when I was a teacher, it was a free extension called rowCall and was very popular with teachers in the Chrome Web store,had over 22,000 users. It is not available anywhere now and really don't know what to do.

Comment: Some emails have probably been sent to the address defined with the instructions requested by the reviewer. Try to see in the mailbox.

Comment: Google is currently migrating from the Web Chrome Store to G Suite Marketplace, so there are still some issues. If you republished your Add-on before the start of the new year, maybe try it again, because it looks likes since the beginning of 2020 the publishing process works better.

Comment: The Publish button is not live (it's gray) and just says "under review". Not sure who's email it's sent to?

Comment: Oh, wow! I just saw that it's "Approved" !!! Thanks for responding. Love this community.